# How can I install global node modules on openshift?

Tags: node.js, ssh, npm, openshift, sequelize.js

I need to install the node.js module sequelize-cli as global to use database migrations on my sequelize ORM schema from the ssh command line. To install the module, can I run an ssh command like:

```
npm install -g sequelize-cli
```

How could it be managed when the application scale?

Answer (score 1):

In your package.json like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "install": "npm install -g sequelize-cli"
}
```

Comment: From https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-scripts.html: Don't use install. Use a .gyp file for compilation, and prepublish for anything else.

You should almost never have to explicitly set a preinstall or install script. If you are doing this, please consider if there is another option. Is this case THE exception?